# End of file exception - Merge pdf using pdfbox

Tags: java, amazon-s3, pdfbox

I have pdf files on S3 and would like to merge into one pdf.

I am using array of Inputstream reading file from s3 and then doing merge using pdf merge utility.
Below code works fine while adding all inputstream at once ( after for loop ) but doesn't work for individual inputstream.  Missing something on IO operation on inputstream like closing stream :(

```
     for (PS3ObjectStream pFileS3Obj: PS3ObjectStream ) {
                    try {
                        pdfMerger.addSource(pFileS3Obj.getS3ObjectInputStream());
                        
                    }catch(Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
pdfMerger.mergeDocuments(MemoryUsageSetting.setupMainMemoryOnly());
}
```

Not working:

```
for (PS3ObjectStream pFileS3Obj: PS3ObjectStream ) {
                try {
                    pdfMerger.addSource(pFileS3Obj.getS3ObjectInputStream());
                    pdfMerger.mergeDocuments(MemoryUsageSetting.setupMainMemoryOnly());
                }catch(Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
}
```

I am getting error : End-of-file , expected line exception.

Any pointers on how should I look into this issue.

```
java.io.IOException: Error: End-of-File, expected line
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.BaseParser.readLine(BaseParser.java:1107)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.COSParser.parseHeader(COSParser.java:2650)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.COSParser.parsePDFHeader(COSParser.java:2633)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser.parse(PDFParser.java:219)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:1230)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:1148)
at org.apache.pdfbox.multipdf.PDFMergerUtility.legacyMergeDocuments(PDFMergerUtility.java:455)
at org.apache.pdfbox.multipdf.PDFMergerUtility.mergeDocuments(PDFMergerUtility.java:346)
at com.djcs.pslintegration.pdfutility.mergeService.MergePdfFileService.mergePDfFiles(MergePdfFileService.java:92)
at com.djcs.pslintegration.pdfutility.mergeService.MergePdfFileService.combinePdfFiles(MergePdfFileService.java:47)
at com.djcs.pslintegration.pdfutility.controller.PDFUtilityController.combinePdfFiles(PDFUtilityController.java:98)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1743)
```

Comment: PDF is either empty or not a PDF at all. Please share the code you're using and the actual stack trace, and the PDFBox version you're using. PDFs start with "%PDF".

Comment: @TilmanHausherr added stack trace

Comment: Definitively a header problem. Try saving `pFileS3Obj.getS3ObjectInputStream()` into a file to see what's in there with `Files.write(Paths.get("/tmp/yourfile.pdf"), IOUtils.toByteArray(pFileS3Obj.getS3ObjectInputStream()));`  (closing of input streams ommitted)

Comment: @TilmanHausherr its valid pdf file. when i am adding all input stream responses in one pdfs it works fine , but giving error when individually adding response into file. updated question

Comment: My requirement is to Merge one file at a time and capture any failed file into response object , with Second option i will not be able to capture any failed file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `PDFMergerUtility` keeps a list of sources and does not reset that after `mergeDocuments()` is done, so what you're doing in the second code segment is to re-run the merging on the same list of input streams several times, despite that the first input stream has already been consumed.

> My requirement is to Merge one file at a time and capture any failed
> file into response object , with Second option i will not be able to
> capture any failed file

So if you want to merge one file at a time, then it would be better to use the `appendDocument()` method instead of the `mergeDocuments()` method (and start with am empty PDDocument, and load the current PDDocument from s3 before the call).

Here's a code attempt (I can't test it because I don't use s3; there's also the risk that `source` is closed too early if any resources are used in the destination).

```
PDDocument destination = new PDDocument();
for (PS3ObjectStream pFileS3Obj : PS3ObjectStream)
{
    PDFMergerUtility pdfMerger = new PDFMergerUtility();
    PDDocument source;
    try (InputStream is = pFileS3Obj.getS3ObjectInputStream())
    {
        source = PDDocument.load(is);
    }
    catch (IOException)
    {
        // do something
    }
    try
    {
        appendDocument(destination, source);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // do something
    }
    finally
    {
        source.close();
    }
}
destination.save(...);
destination.close();
```

Comment: Can we reset source ? how i can achieve Merging files one at a time and  capture failed files

Comment: Failed files would be bad PDFs, so put a try-catch around `load()`. This way you'd still have the result PDDocument.

Comment: I am getting socket connection reset exception while trying to load () . above solution works fine when number of documents are less :( I am trying 3000+ docs  merge.

Comment: That's not a pdfbox problem but an s3 problem. Maybe there is a limit. You should discuss this with Amazon.

Comment: Above code works OK , but when merging 5000+ Docs its taking hours to Merge PDF file where as download from S3 is super Quick . Is there any way to improve performance ?

Comment: I don't know, this would need to be simulated somehow to find out what goes slower and slower. My guess is that more memory is needed.

Comment: I am using 30 GB of total memory and application is running at -Xmx8000m..