# PDF Box: Merge Documents vs append Documents - performance

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am doing merge using pdfbox and java , I have input-stream object list which contains pdf files.

Currently it's taking longer time (hours) to merge documents when merging 5000 plus docs.
Basically i need to iterate through all the files and capture any Invalid file as failed response file

what's the best way to improve performance?

Option 1:

```
for (PdfFileObjectStream pdfFileObject : pdfFileObjectStream) {
    
        
        try (InputStream is = pdfFileObject.getObjectInputStream())
        {
            source = PDDocument.load(is);
            pdfMerger.appendDocument(destination, source);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //Add to failed file
        }
        
    }   


LOG.info("File merged");
```

Option2:

```
for (PdfFileObjectStream pdfFileObject : pdfFileObjectStream) {
            try {
                
               pdfMerger.addSource(pdfFileObject.getObjectInputStream());
               
            }catch(Exception e) {
                ////Add to failed file
                continue;
            }

        }

        pdfMerger.mergeDocuments(MemoryUsageSetting.setupMainMemoryOnly());
        LOG.info("File merged");
```

I have configured good JVM Memory for application.

Comment: @KJ merging isn't GPU related

Comment: You could try optimized mode but I think you already did (I remember this question elsewhere)

Comment: @TilmanHausherr yes its continuing to existing question.. Can we run merge in parallel  like Spiling List into sub lists and running multiple threads for merge

Comment: @TilmanHausherr   are you referring below as Optimized mode ? 
 pdfMerger.setDocumentMergeMode(DocumentMergeMode.OPTIMIZE_RESOURCES_MODE);

Comment: Yes. But this works only if you call `mergeDocuments`. And this loses certain elements, e.g. structure tree, acroform, etc. You could try to merge in parallel if the documents are unrelated.

Comment: hmm  I Need to maintain sequencing  of Docs if done in parallel

Comment: You could download a certain amount of PDFs and then merge them in an extra thread of a thread pool, then the next batch, etc.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Can we disable Warnings from pdfbox ?  eg. -  WARN 3164 --- [      Finalizer] org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSDocument        : Warning: You did not close a PDF Document 
 I have closed doc in finally block

Comment: You didn't close a document. You think you did.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr  -- using similar code sample  for append method https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73074763/end-of-file-exception-merge-pdf-using-pdfbox/73103450?noredirect=1#comment129769594_73103450

Comment: destination doesn't get closed there.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Cannot close destination before all file append successfully, it will error out for early file closing :(  do you have any other approach ?

Comment: You need to close it when all is done. So you have to hold that object, or the GC will close it for you. Also make sure you have the latest version of your jdk.

Comment: Yes thats what i am doing closing destination after for loop {} ... as its doing append in for loop i am getting "Warning: You did not close a PDF Document"  Is there way to disable this runtime Warning

Comment: You could disable it by configuring your logger, but the best solution is to find the cause. What jdk version and what pdfbox version are you using?